# Qual a melhor forma de usar um middleware em um controller?

Tags: laravel, middleware

Vejo que existem duas formas de usar um middleware em um controller laravel, usando ele na rota especifica, ou usando ele no construct do controller.Então eu gostaria de saber, qual seria a melhor forma e por quê? Existe alguma outra forma?

```
Route::get('profile', [UserController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth');
```

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth');
   $this->middleware('log')->only('index');
   $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Usando o middleware na rota específica:**
Vantagens:
É uma abordagem mais granular, permitindo aplicar middlewares apenas em rotas específicas.
Proporciona maior flexibilidade ao definir quais rotas requerem autenticação ou outros tipos de verificação.
Desvantagens:
Pode exigir a repetição do middleware em várias rotas semelhantes, caso seja necessário aplicá-lo em várias delas.
Pode resultar em um número maior de linhas de código no arquivo de rotas, especialmente em projetos maiores com muitas rotas.

---

**Usando o middleware no construtor do controller:**
Vantagens:
Centraliza a aplicação dos middlewares em um local único, facilitando a manutenção e evitando repetições.
Permite aplicar middlewares de forma mais abrangente em todos os métodos do controller ou apenas em métodos específicos.
Desvantagens:
Pode dificultar a visualização dos middlewares aplicados, uma vez que estão definidos no construtor do controller e não nas rotas.
Pode exigir a criação de métodos adicionais no controller para definir exceções ou configurações específicas de cada middleware.